# To Merge two rows using SQL

Tags: sql

I am stuck in a situation where with my SQL query I am getting an output as below.
[image]

I want my output to be of single row so that the end user have a glance at the report and can easily guess which are the event that guy has attended as below.

[image]

Comment: You can put some effort to post data here with the description instead of using images. And mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also: which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single row, use `GROUP BY`:

```
select fname, lname, max(event1) as Event1, max(event2) as event2
from t
group by fname, lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every person has events including both `yes` and `no`, you can use below query to generate your desired result. If both values are `no`, you will get `no` in result then.

```
SELECT fname,
       lname,
       max(event1) as event1,
       max(event2) as event2
FROM t1
GROUP BY fname,
         lname;
```

**Result:**

```
fname   lname   event1  event2
------------------------------
abc      xyz     yes     yes
```

you can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/FAEZ87895)**

Comment: Then, what's the @Gordon posted 5minutes before than you ?

Comment: @Suraz, I start working on the demo when i read the question. Gordan answer was posted in the meanwhile. when i created the sample data, write the query and simulated it, then i posted the answer. Don't you think writing that much lines and then posting answer required at least 5 min? You can check my others answers as well.  everyone has demo attached. Thanks

Comment: In this way, you will be the last  for every questions and keep posting similar answers most of time. We are here to look for the quick and elegant answers, however we can create demo as well but only whenever required.

Comment: @Suraz, For comment `you will be the last for every questions and keep posting similar answers most of time`, you can check my other answers. Most of the answers are elegant and timely. I admit that it's a mistake to post the same answer, but it was not intentional and i think if i put effort in re-creating the whole scenario,  It need to be posted as new answer(or even better to edit the existing answer which in current case i was unaware of) so that it may help any beginner.

Comment: @Suraz: I respect every senior [and you are one of them :-)] and i also understand your point but i was just clarifying that this was not a cheating attempt. Sorry i mean no offense. Your comments are learning opportunity for me and next time i will be more careful. Thanks :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154337/discussion-between-zarruq-and-suraz).